# SQL, know last value saved on a table of a few parameters

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table like:

```
+----------+--------------+---------+
| NAME     | DATE         | VALUE   |
+----------+--------------+---------+
|  A       | 2015-06-01   |      32 | 
|  B       | 2015-06-01   |      33 | 
|  C       | 2015-06-01   |      34 | 
|  A       | 2015-06-03   |      24 | 
|  A       | 2015-06-02   |      30 | 
|  B       | 2015-06-05   |      45 | 
|  B       | 2015-06-02   |      65 | 
|  A       | 2015-05-29   |      31 | 
|  A       | 2015-05-28   |      57 | 
|  C       | 2015-06-02   |      58 | 
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

I need to do an mySql query that returns me:

```
+----------+---------+

| NAME     | VALUE   |
+----------+---------+
|  A       |      24 |
|  B       |      45 |
+----------+---------+
```

It means, the query has to return from an specific name (A & B in this example) the last value (more recent date) saved for this name ( A on 3d June was 24 and B on 5th June was 45).

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes This is possible...

Comment: Start by going though the example here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result

```
 SELECT b.name, (SELECT VALUE FROM mytable a WHERE a.name = b.name ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1) 
 FROM mytable b
    -- where b.name in ('A', 'B') 
    GROUP BY b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT NAME,VALUE FROM mytable WHERE `DATE` IN
> ```
>
> (SELECT MAX(`DATE`) FROM mytable GROUP BY `NAME`)

Above sql will give you desire output.

Thank you.